# Any algorithm to do image minification?

Tags: graphics

I'am trying to implement super-sampling to do anti-aliasing. I enlarge the original frame buffer by 16 times, which means 4 times larger both in height and width. Now my problem is I don't know how to minify the 16x image. I know that I can choose the nearest four pixels to linearly interpolate if the sampling image 4 times larger. But with 16 times larger image, I have 16 nearest pixels, right?

Comment: You could choose the 8 nearest pixels instead.

Comment: I found an algorithm called bicubic interpolation. I think it will work for me.